# How does zero-width negative lookahead assertions work in R?

Tags: r, regex

the output of

```
strsplit('abc dcf', split = '(?=c)', perl = T)
```

is as expected.

However, the output of

```
strsplit('abc dcf', split = '(?!c)', perl = T)
```

is

```
[[1]]
[1] "a" "b" "c" " " "d" "c" "f"
```

while my expectation is

```
[[1]]
[1] "a"  "b"  "c " "d"  "cf"
```

becasue I thought it wouldn't be splited if the last character of previous chunk matches the char `c`. Is my understanding of negative lookahead wrong?

Comment: `(?<!c)` is a negative lookbehind, not negative lookahead that is `(?!c)`

Comment: @Toto. That seems not the issue. `strsplit('abc dcf', split = '(?!c)', perl = T)` give the same output as `strsplit('abc dcf', split = '(?<!c)', perl = T)` and I edited the question a little based on your comment.

Comment: It does not really matter if it is a positive or negative lookahead. What matters is how `strsplit` deals with zero-length matches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can try

```
strsplit('abc dcf', "(?![c ])\\s*\\b", perl=TRUE)
#[[1]]
#[1] "a"  "b"  "c " "d"  "cf"
```

Comment: HI. could you explain why my code does not work? I am still confused. In addition, I don't need to remove the space.

Comment: @mt1022 Updated the post by not removing the space